# How to use Redux time travel to handle errors

Tags: javascript, exception, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to figure out how to handle errors in React/Redux application and figured out that Redux allows to traverse the state continuum backwards due the immutable state pattern. Is it crazy idea to traverse back in time on Redux if post fails, same time incrementing component's internal retry counter, and eventually dispatch necessary actions? How would I go to previous state with react-redux?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is a pattern called "optimistic updates".  For example, you dispatch an action before a network call under the assumption that the network call will succeed.  If the call fails, then you dispatch a second action to revert the first one.

"Time-travel debugging" requires use of the Redux DevTools.  The DevTools actually record all actions dispatched, and when you jump back and forth in the history, will replay the actions up to that point to determine what the current state should be.  In production, old actions and old states are not recorded (although you could certainly build something yourself to do that sort of thing).

Answer (score -1):

You can use redux developer tools for chrome to avail nice UI/UX of time travelling. Go ahead and install redux dev tools on Chrome store.

Also, you'll need to tell your redux store that you're using redux dev tools. For that you'll want to make some tweaks in your `createStore()` method.

Take a look at the description of [this repo](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to see it in action.

Refer to this code to inject a dev-tool enhancer in your redux store-

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import createReducer from './reducers';

const devtools = window.devToolsExtension || (() => noop => noop);

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, middlewares) {
  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    devtools(),
  ];

  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    initialState,
    compose(...enhancers)
  );

  return store;
}
```